# MathNet.Numerics find indices of minimums in a matrix that meet a condition

Tags: c#, mathnet-numerics

I'm trying to find the indices of the minimum values in a `Matrix<float>` with `MathNet.Numerics`, but only for the values that meet a certain condition (in this case `value >= 0`).
I can find one of the minimum actual values like this:

```cs
var mat = Matrix<float>.Build.DenseOfArray(new float[,] {
    {2, 3, 1},
    {3, -1, 5},
    {1, 4, 3}
});

var min = mat.Enumerate().Where(x => x >= 0).Min();
```

But I would like to find the indices of both 1's (and not the -1). So the result should be [0,2] and [2,0].

**ANSWER:**

I found a possible way to do it, not sure if this is the best/fastest way:

```cs
var min = mat.Enumerate().Where(x => x >= 0).Min();
var allMin = mat.EnumerateIndexed().Where(x => x.Item3 == min).ToList();
```

Comment: What is the output you are getting with this code?

Comment: The output now is just the float 1